# HL7 accelerator error: Schema not found (after upgrade to BizTalk 2013)

Tags: biztalk, btahl7, hl7-v2, biztalk-2013

On a dev machine, we upgraded a BizTalk 2010 server to BizTalk 2013.  We are sending HL72 messaves from another machine to this one and getting a schema not found error:

Alternate Error Number: 301
 Alternate Error Description: Schema http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X#ORU_R01_23_GLO_DEF not found
 Alternate Encoding System: HL7-BTA

The message specifies "LAB" as the sending application, and we have a party called "LAB" which specifies "`http://mycompany/myapplication/HL7/2X/2.3/ORU/v1`" as the schema namespace, so we can't figure out why it's looking for the ORU R01 2.3 schema in the *default microsoft* namespace.

[image]

Our message looks as follows:

```
MSH|^~\&|LAB|ABC|LAB||201311071138||ORU^R01|D2863329|D|2.3|
PID|1|A00003766|XX00014202|9191610101|Ihhendrickson^Plis||19691202|M|||8423 Panko Pvt^^Here^BC^XXX XXX||111-1111|||||xx0055355x3|9x9x6x0x0x|
PV1|1|R|TRAKBHLB||||93190^Plisihd^xxxxxx^^^Dr^^xxxxxx|||||||||||RCR||BC|||||||||||||||||||xxxxx||REG|||201207261453|
ORC|RE|PT80755100.0010|||CM|N|||201311071138|^xxxxxx^Linda^^^^^xxxx||93190^xxxx^Aaron^^^Dr^^xxxx|xxx|
OBR|1|PT0711:T00001R100.0010|PT0711:T00001R|100.0010^Group \T\ Screen^00050252^34532-2^Blood Type \T\ Indirect Antibody Screen^pCLOCD|R|201311071004|201311071004|||G|||PLIS Testing|201311071004|T|93190^Plisihd^xxx^^^Dr^^Pxxxxx||00050252|||xxx|201311071004||BBK|F|||93190^xxx^Aaron^^^Dr^^xxxx|
NTE|1||Date required: 20131107|
NTE|2||Any previous transfusions? Unknown|
NTE|3||Specify any underlying blood disorders: U|
NTE|4||Has consent for blood products been obtained? Yes|
OBX|1|ST|150.0100^Patient Blood Group^00050252^882-1^Blood Type \T\ Indirect Antibody Screen^pCLOCD||OPOS^O Rh Pos|||||A~S|F|||201311071137|xx^xx^L|IH001^^Blood Group^Patient Blood Group^150.0100|
OBX|2|ST|200.0100^Ab Screen Gel^00050252^XBC1931-6^Blood Type \T\ Indirect Antibody Screen^pCLOCD||NEGATIVE^NEGATIVE|||||A~S|F|||201311071138|xx^xx^L|IH001^^Ab Scr Gel^Antibody Screen Gel^200.0100|
ZDR||xxx^xxxx^Aaron^^^Dr^^^^^^^^^ATP|
ZPR||
```

Anyone have ideas we should try?

Answer (score 2):

For send ports, the HL7 2.X Assembler component is supposed to [use the MSH 5 field value to determine the party to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee409280%28v=bts.80%29.aspx). The pipeline configuration on your send port should have an option to enable partial name resolution (`EnablePartialNameResolutionForReceivingApplication`), which—when turned on—may help.

In receive locations, the HL7 2X Disassembler component [should use MSH 3 for party resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee409379%28v=bts.80%29.aspx). The receive location's BTAHL72XReceivePipeline configuration has settings called `EnablePartialNameResolutionForSendingApplication` and `EnablePartialNameResolutionForReceivingApplication` for you to turn on.

Older versions of BizTalk required [a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977120) to make those settings work, but that should no longer be necessary. From that page, the description of the settings are:

*For the send pipeline, the BTAHL7 2.X assembler contains the following property:*

```
Property name: Enable Partial Name Resolution For Receiving Application 
Default value: False 
Description for the property:
First check party with name MSH5.1 + MSH5.2 + MSH5.3. If not found, check party with name MSH5.1 + MSH5.2. If not found, check with name MSH5.1.
```

*For the receive pipeline, the BTAHL7 2.X disassembler contains the following properties:*

```
Property name: Enable Partial Name Resolution For Receiving Application 
Default value: False 
Description for the property:
First check party with name MSH5.1 + MSH5.2 + MSH5.3. If not found, check party with name MSH5.1 + MSH5.2. If not found, check with name MSH5.1.
Property name: Enable Partial Name Resolution For Sending Application 
Default value: False 
Description for the property:
First check party with name MSH3.1 + MSH3.2 + MSH3.3. If not found, check party with name MSH3.1 + MSH3.2. If not found, check with name MSH3.1.
```

If that does not help, then there is one other thing to try for send ports only: In the party configuration, try assigning the party to your send port, as described in step three [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226496%28v=bts.80%29.aspx). That's one way to try to force it to use the proper party. That will not help with receive locations, though.

Comment: This is for send pipelines, our issue is with receiving

Comment: I updated my answer to also include the partial name resolution pipeline component setting for receive locations. Can you try/have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

There are know issues with doing a BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2013 in-place upgrade, possibly it is due to one of the below.  It would be best not to do in in place upgrade, but rather do a clean install and migrate applications.

1. [In Place upgrade of BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2013 does not update the Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/apacbiztalk/archive/2013/11/01/in-place-upgrade-of-biztalk-2010-to-biztalk-2013-does-not-update-the-microsoft-biztalk-globalpropertyschemas.aspx)
2. [Upgrading BizTalk Server 2010 to 2013 – need to provision permissions on BizTalkMgmtDb.bts_dynamic_sendport_handlers table](http://adventuresinsidethemessagebox.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/upgrading-biztalk-server-2010-to-2013-need-to-provision-permissions-on-biztalkmgmtdb-bts_dynamic_sendport_handlers-table/)
3. [Upgrading to BizTalk 2013–Could not load file or assembly "’Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient](http://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/upgrading-to-biztalk-2013could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-biztalk-interop-ssoclient/)

Comment: Also, see my post about Parties being ignored. Only after a fresh OS reinstall will BizTalk 2013 parties work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848912/biztalk-party-not-being-resolved-for-incoming-hl7v2-message